# Updating collection of primitive and complex types in OData

Tags: odata

Is it possible to update entity properties corresponding to collections of primitive and complex types without sending all the content?

For example, for an entity Question that has a property tags corresponding to a list of string:

- POST /OData.sac/questions/tags to add an element to the list
- DELETE /OData.sac/questions/tags with the value as query parameters to delete it from the list

and something similar for complex types.

Such mechanism is supported for navigation properties.

Thanks very such for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to partially update a collection property. It's something we thought about a lot and it's something we knew we would get asks for, but we just couldn't make the tradeoff work. To fully support partial updates we would need to have a way to identify individual members of a collection. This doesn't exist yet.

We are considering at least allowing the two operations (create and delete) you've suggested above in OData 4.1. See issues [615](https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-615) and [616](https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-616) in the OASIS issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, Mark! I agree that using the query parameter $filter is the right approach ;-)

Comment: Are the working drafts of 4.1 (or 4.01) available to the public anywhere? Is there any way to see and participate in the spec discussions as an outsider who can't afford an OASIS membership?